# manifest.json reference a text file instead of a string

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension, reference, manifest.json

I want to reference a text file (in this case sites.txt), instead of having it inside the manifest file, so I can easily edit it.  As well as save on file size.
Is this possible?  I have seen people have extensions that have a whitelist that users can change.

Manifest.json file and others at https://github.com/zekrom-vale/Skip-adf.ly

The example would be:

```
`{
...
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": sites.txt,
      "js": ["skip.js"]
    }]
}`
```

Where sites.txt is

```
"http://adf.ly/*","http://atominik.com/*",...
```

The problem is if the file is "sites.txt" I believe it will just run on sites.txt (or get an error) and not get the pages to run on.

Thank you for a response!

Comment: Also I want to do this with permissions too.

Comment: No, it's not possible. Those extensions simply inject the content script on matching sites or use a dumb location.href check in a content script that runs on all pages. As for permissions, read the documentation for optional permissions.

Comment: Well, that does make sense as permissions is listed before you install the extension and would cause security issues.

Comment: If you'll choose the selective injection method, consider using [declarativeContent's RequestContentScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent) (ignore the warning message).